# Convert single byte to string and back to byte

Tags: java

I'm attempting to convert a single byte to a string and then back again to the original byte. The assertion below fails however. Any suggestions  would be deeply appreciated

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

    public class ByteTest {
        private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
        @Test
        public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            byte b = (byte)(220);
            String s = new String(new byte[]{b}, CHARSET);
            byte[] parsed = s.getBytes(CHARSET);
            assertEquals(b, parsed[0]); //fails
        }
    }
```

Comment: `byte` can't really store 220.

Comment: A single `(byte) 220` is not a valid UTF-8 encoded string!

Comment: @SteveSmith No, but it can store `-36` which is the signed equivalent of an unsigned `220` byte. It's the same thing, you just interpret it differently.

Comment: You could have a look at the `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary` and `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary` which work with byte arrays. (maybe too powerful for a single byte...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte 220 (0xDC) by itself is invalid UTF-8. A [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character starting with a byte 0xA1..0xF5 requires a second byte.

Try another encoding, e.g. ISO-8859-1, which has effectively 1-to-1 byte-to-character round trip in Java.

```
public class ByteTest {
    private static final String CHARSET = "ISO-8859-1";

    @Test
    public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte b = (byte) (220);
        String s = new String(new byte[] { b }, CHARSET);
        byte[] parsed = s.getBytes(CHARSET);
        assertEquals(b, parsed[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only practically? Can you give an example of a multibyte ISO-Latin1 character?

Comment: Not all byte values are valid ISO-8859-1, so technically it's illegal to parse bytes 0x81 .. 0x9F as ISO-8859-1. But all Java versions that exist today accept any byte value as  valid ISO-8859-1.